# Visual basic express sql statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, datagrid, sql-server-2014

I'm currently programming a software with a SQL Server 2014 and I'm stuck !

I'm trying to use the value I get from a list box to insert it to my SQL query in order to process the query and get some result here is my code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
        SQL.RunQuery(" SELECT '" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & " '  FROM test ")
        If SQL.SQLdataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = SQL.SQLdataset.Tables(0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

My issue is that it just displays surname all over the datagrid or firstname all over the datagrid when it is selected :/

I can't find the problem please help :/

Comment: you are just selecting ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() (+ a space) for every row in your table. Remove the single quotes and the query will run. BUT you should consider using parameters then concatinating your sqls

Comment: @deterministicFail yeah it works like a charm !
using parameters ? im new to VB and sql , could you maybe give me an example please ?

Comment: im not using vb but parameters are mostly the same in every language. I didnt read this article entirly, but i think its a good start: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/learnvbnet/a/begdbapp9.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you do as follows will fix the issue

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
        SQL.RunQuery(" SELECT [" & ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() & "]  FROM test ")
        If SQL.SQLdataset.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = SQL.SQLdataset.Tables(0)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The passed named is being treated as a **literal string**, adding Square brackets will enforce sql server to treat it as an object name(column name in this case).